# How to specify model directory in Floydhub?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning

I am new to Floydhub. I am trying to run the code from [this github repository](https://github.com/dennybritz/chatbot-retrieval/) and the corresponding tutorial.

For the training, I successfully used this command:

```
 floyd run --gpu --env tensorflow-1.2 --data janinanu/dataset 
 /data/2:tut_train 'python udc_train.py'
```

I adjusted this line in the training file to work in Floydhub:

```
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("input_dir", "/tut_train", "Directory containing 
input data files 'train.tfrecords' and 'validation.tfrecords'")
```

As said, this worked without problems for the training.

Now for the testing, I do not really find any details on how to specify the model directory in which the output of the training gets stored. I mounted the output from training with model_dir as mount point. I assumed that the correct command should look something like this:

```
floyd run --cpu --env tensorflow-1.2 --data janinanu/datasets
/data/2:tut_test --data janinanu/projects/retrieval-based-dialogue-system-
on-ubuntu-corpus/18/output:model_dir 'python udc_test.py     
--model_dir=?'
```

I have no idea what to put in the `--model_dir=?`

Correspondingly, I assumed that I have to adjust some lines in the test file:

```
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("test_file", "/tut_test/test.tfrecords", "Path of   
test data in TFRecords format")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("model_dir", "/model_dir", "Directory to load model    
checkpoints from")
```

...as well as in the train file (not sure about that though...):

```
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("input_dir", "/tut_train", "Directory containing  
input data files 'train.tfrecords' and 'validation.tfrecords'")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("model_dir", "/model_dir", "Directory to store   
model checkpoints (defaults to /model_dir)")
```

When I use e.g. `--model_dir=/model_dir` and the code with the above adjustments, I get this error:

```
2017-12-22 12:17:49,048 INFO - return func(*args, **kwargs)
2017-12-22 12:17:49,048 INFO - File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-       
packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", 
line 543, in evaluate
2017-12-22 12:17:49,048 INFO - log_progress=log_progress)
2017-12-22 12:17:49,049 INFO - File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", 
line 816, in _evaluate_model
2017-12-22 12:17:49,049 INFO - % self._model_dir)
2017-12-22 12:17:49,049 INFO - 
tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators._sklearn.NotFittedError: 
Couldn't find trained model at /model_dir
```

Which doesn't come as a surprise.

Can anyone give me some clarification on how to feed the training output into the test run?

I will also post this question in the Floydhub Forum.

Thanks!!

.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount the output of any job just like you mount a data. In your example:

`--data janinanu/projects/retrieval-based-dialogue-system-
on-ubuntu-corpus/18/output:model_dir`

should mount the entire output directory from run 18 to `/mount_dir` of the new job.

You can confirm this by viewing the job page (select the "data" tab to see what datasets are mounted at which paths).

In you case, can you confirm if the test is looking for the correct model filename?

I will also respond to this in the FloydHub forum.